# Подсчет количества встречающихся ip адресов в файле

Tags: python, сеть, unix

пишу скрипт для автоматизации на python,необходимо посчитать количество повторяющихся ip адресов(эти адреса добавляет другой скрипт)в файле,подсчитать их,а дальше я уже сам,с подсчетом у меня большие проблемы,прошу помочь,к примеру:
file.txt

- 10.255.110.10
- 10.255.110.10
- 10.255.114.11
- 172.16.35.140
- 172.16.35.145
- 172.16.35.15
- 172.16.35.19
- 10.255.23.23
- 172.16.35.48
- 10.255.23.7
- 10.125.16.7
- 10.255.23.10
- 10.255.110.10
- 10.255.114.11
- 172.16.35.140
- 172.16.35.145
- 172.16.35.15

И т.д.

Не получается написать так,чтобы было к примеру :Такой то ip :30 раз,
Постоянно ip:1 раз,делаю перебор циклом и подсчет

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283874/python-count-duplicate-in-list - второй ответ прям для Вас. просто и со вкусом.

```
l =['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '1.1.1.1']

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(l) 
print(c)
```

На выходе будет мапа вида

```
{ '1.1.1.1':2, '2.2.2.2':1}
```

Как загрузить с файла в список - тут уж самостоятельно

Если же в линукс, то можно и без питонового кода. Где то так

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)